# JQuery .inArray() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Okay, so I am working on a weather application, and I wrote the following test code to verify that the user entered a valid state abbreviation:

```
var input = prompt("What state are you in?");
var lower = input.toLowerCase();
var categories = [ 
    "ma", 
    "ny", 
    "ct", 
    "ri", 
],
var found = $.inArray(lower, categories);
if (found > -1) {
    alert("Cool!");
    }
else {
    alert("Oh no!");
    }
```

But for some reason, it doesn't work.

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/B24Bg/

Does anyone know why this is?  I probably just made a silly mistake, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: extra comma at the end of array

Comment: And another one before `var`. This fiddle doesn't compile...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your console window in your browser, press F12, there are errors.

The comma after ] should be a semi-colon:

```
var input = prompt("What state are you in?");
var lower = input.toLowerCase();
var categories = [ 
    "ma", 
    "ny", 
    "ct", 
    "ri"
];
var found = $.inArray(lower, categories);
if (found > -1) {
    alert("Cool!");
    }
else {
    alert("Oh no!");
    }
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/B24Bg/1/)

Comment: Yup, silly mistake!  Thanks for finding it and pointing it out.